# Angular http response need help being able to iterate through the response on subscribe

Tags: arrays, angular, object, observable, httprequest

I have a component that makes a call to service method which makes an http request. I am unable to iterate through the returned response.

> Component

```
this.mappingService
  .getLocationByBoundingBoxSearch(
    upperLeftLatitude,
    upperLeftLongitude,
    bottomRightLatitude,
    bottomRightLongitude,
    maxResults,
    locationType,
    requestUser,
    userClientIPAddress,
    systemSourceCodeId,
    cesServiceTypeToInclude,
    cesServiceTypeToExclude,
    entityTypes,
    competitorTypes
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (centersWithStorageData) => {
      this.centersWithStorage = centersWithStorageData;

      console.log(centersWithStorageData);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(centersWithStorageData.));

      this.centersWithStorage.forEach(centerStorage => {
        let ceterStorageIcon : PinIcon = {
          Location: centerStorage.Location,
          Unicode: '\uf005',
          fontName: 'FontAwesome',
          fontSizePx: 30,
          color: '#e74a3b'
          };
          this.createFontPushpin(ceterStorageIcon)
      });
```

this.centersWithStorage is of type any.

> MappingService

```
getLocationByBoundingBoxSearch(upperLeftLatitude: any, upperLeftLongitude: any, bottomRightLatitude: any, bottomRightLongitude: any,
                               maxResults: any, LocationType: any, requestUser: any, userClientIPAddress: any,
                               systemSourceCodeId: any, cesServiceTypeToInclude?: any, cesServiceTypeToExclude?: any, 
                               entityTypes?: any, competitorTypes?: any){

    const paramsObj = {
        "upperLeftLatitude": upperLeftLatitude,
        "upperLeftLongitude": upperLeftLongitude,
        "bottomRightLatitude": bottomRightLatitude,
        "bottomRightLongitude": bottomRightLongitude,
        "maxResults": maxResults,
        "LocationType": LocationType,
        "requestUser": requestUser,
        "userClientIPAddress": userClientIPAddress,
        "systemSourceCodeId": systemSourceCodeId,
        "cesServiceTypeToInclude": cesServiceTypeToInclude,
        "cesServiceTypeToExclude": cesServiceTypeToExclude,
        "entityTypes": entityTypes,
        "competitorTypes": competitorTypes
    }
    return this.http.get(this.mappingServiceApiUrl + "/LocationByBoundingBoxSearch", {params: paramsObj})
    .pipe(map((res => res)));
}
```

> Block that may need to be altered

```
     return this.http.get(this.mappingServiceApiUrl + "/LocationByBoundingBoxSearch", {params: paramsObj})
    .pipe(map((res => res)));
```

The res is an Object. I can console log the response an it shows and array of objects so i don't know why i can't iterate it from the ts of the component. I don't want to have to make a custom strongly typed object to return as.  Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I realized intellisense on visual studio code was not working properly when typing out this.centersWithStorage.

```
  this.mappingService
  .getLocationByBoundingBoxSearch(
    upperLeftLatitude,
    upperLeftLongitude,
    bottomRightLatitude,
    bottomRightLongitude,
    maxResults,
    locationType,
    requestUser,
    userClientIPAddress,
    systemSourceCodeId,
    cesServiceTypeToInclude,
    cesServiceTypeToExclude,
    entityTypes,
    competitorTypes
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (centersWithStorageData) => {
      this.centersWithStorage = centersWithStorageData;
      this.centersWithStorage.result.cesEntity.forEach(centerStorage => {
```

I was able to use the full dot accessor notation to the properties of the object, and now it works :) i didn't try it before because the properties weren't showing up while typing.

**this.centersWithStorage.result.cesEntity**  was the fix.